# Show the same UI for menu with actionbarsherlock on device pre 2.3 and post 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I developed an application and I wanted to have some less common feature under the 3 square button

On android 4.0, I have the result I want : (3 square button, when I click on it, I have the others features)

[image: example with android 4.0]

On android 2.3, the device has a menu physical button but the feature aren't available because they are overrided (the menu button call the sliding menu).

[image: example with android 2.3]

Is it possible to show the 3 square button on all device with action bar sherlock ? and use the menu physical button to show the sliding menu ?

My menu definition :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_download"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_d_download"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/download"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_print"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_d_print"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:title="@string/print"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_d_share"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_accept"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_d_accept"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/ok"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_d_delete"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:title="@string/delete"/>

</menu>
```

When I see the documentation of android:showAsAction, I didn't find a value that would help http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html
Regards

Comment: Note that there is no MENU physical button on many Android devices.

Comment: well I know it. I added the feature to show the sliding menu if it was available. If not, user can swipe from the left of the screen.

Comment: Actionbar sherlock does the trick

Comment: I added my layout definition on the question. otherwise it will be difficult to see what's the problem

Comment: If you're going to use ActionBarSherlock, then please read [this](http://jakewharton.com/deprecated-from-inception/) post from its author Jake Wharton.

Comment: @ChuongPham Actionbarsherlock was the only solution when I began to code. I read your message and I migrate. It wasn't easy but I'd like to thanks you. Regards